# Css is not loaded with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I can't load my styles using webpack - I have a couple of `.scss` files, webpack should compile them to `.css` files and generate JS output file. The file is generated correctly, but the `.css` files are just not there. What can be wrong with my config?:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

const sassLoaders = [
    'css-loader',
    'sass-loader?indentedSyntax=sass&includePaths[]=' + DIST_DIR
]

const config = {
    entry: {
        app: [APP_DIR + '/index.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loaders: ['babel']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: DIST_DIR,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', sassLoaders.join('!'))
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/bundle.js',
        path: DIST_DIR
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css')
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.scss'],
        root: [APP_DIR]
    }
}

module.exports = config
```

File structure:

```
dist
 - css
   - style.scss
 - js
src
 - index.js
```

Comment: You should be matching against a `.scss` extension not `.sass`. Try changing your `test` key to `/\.scss$/`

Comment: Sure, just a typo, it doesn't change anything in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your module loaders for your SCSS files to:

```
{ test: /\.s[ac]ss(\?|$)/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'] }
```